# Computing Math calculation based on row content in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to Mysql and trying to figure out a way to do a simple Math calculation between rows, below is the sample of view that i am using and i want to calculate few basic function

```
+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
|   Buy_cty_rgn   | total | Sntmt | Sntmt_Calc |
+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
| Central Chennai |    24 | D     |            |
| Central Chennai |    11 | I     |            |
| Central Chennai |     2 | S     |            |
| Central Chennai |    37 | All   |            |
| North Chennai   |    11 | D     |            |
| North Chennai   |    17 | I     |            |
| North Chennai   |     2 | S     |            |
| North Chennai   |    30 | All   |            |
| South Chennai   |   113 | D     |            |
| South Chennai   |   108 | I     |            |
| South Chennai   |    28 | S     |            |
| South Chennai   |   249 | All   |            |
| West Chennai    |     7 | D     |            |
| West Chennai    |     8 | I     |            |
| West Chennai    |     6 | S     |            |
| West Chennai    |    21 | All   |            |
| All             |   337 | All   |            |
+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Snt_Calc = ((Total where Sntmt = **D** / total where sntmt = **All**) * 100) - ((Total where Sntmt = **I** / total where sntmt = **all**) * 100)

Desired Output

---

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
| Dmc_Cty |   Buy_cty_rgn   | total | Sntmt | Calc_Sntmt |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
| Chennai | Central Chennai |    24 | D     |            |
| Chennai | Central Chennai |    11 | I     |            |
| Chennai | Central Chennai |     2 | S     |            |
| Chennai | Central Chennai |    37 | All   | 35.14      |
| Chennai | North Chennai   |    11 | D     |            |
| Chennai | North Chennai   |    17 | I     |            |
| Chennai | North Chennai   |     2 | S     |            |
| Chennai | North Chennai   |    30 | All   | -20.00     |
| Chennai | South Chennai   |   113 | D     |            |
| Chennai | South Chennai   |   108 | I     |            |
| Chennai | South Chennai   |    28 | S     |            |
| Chennai | South Chennai   |   249 | All   | 2.01       |
| Chennai | West Chennai    |     7 | D     |            |
| Chennai | West Chennai    |     8 | I     |            |
| Chennai | West Chennai    |     6 | S     |            |
| Chennai | West Chennai    |    21 | All   | -4.76      |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the calculation as a subquery and then join the results back in:

The query to calculate the value:

```
select Dmc_Cty, Buy_cty_rgn,
       (100*sum(case when Sntmt = 'D' then total end) / sum(case when Sntmt = 'All' then total end) -
        100*sum(case when Sntmt = 'I' then total end) / sum(case when Sntmt = 'All' then total end)
       ) as Calc_Sntmt
from table t
group by Dmc_Cty, Buy_cty_rgn;
```

The query to join the result back in:

```
select t.*, (case when t.Sntmt = 'All' then tsum. Calc_Sntmt end) as Calc_Sntmt
from table t left outer join
     (select Dmc_Cty, Buy_cty_rgn,
             (100*sum(case when Sntmt = 'D' then total end) / sum(case when Sntmt = 'All' then total end) -
              100*sum(case when Sntmt = 'I' then total end) / sum(case when Sntmt = 'All' then total end)
             ) as Calc_Sntmt
      from table t
      group by Dmc_Cty, Buy_cty_rgn
     ) tsum
     on tsum.Dmc_Cty = t.Dmc_Cty and
        tsum.Buy_cty_rgn = t.Buy_cty_rgn;
```

Comment: hi Gordon, this code works like a charm. Thanks a ton for helping out.. i have 2 questions though, it will be kind of you if you can help 1.)I am not able to understand the logic of applying left outer Join, may i kindly request you to elaborate on it   2.) There is an additional **'** before **total** with in subquery i tried amending it however, for some reason i am not able to do so on the answer.. how to fix it  - again thanks a ton for saving my skin :)

Comment: The single quote before `total` was a typo.  The `left outer join` is not really necessary.  It just emphasizes that all rows int he first table are maintained in the output.

Comment: thank you for the inputs sir, i now realize that i want to update existing table with **Calc** column output, i tried sever ways to do that however i end up with _Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax;_ can i seek for your guidance ?

Comment: @Mysql_NUb_Sri . . . If you have a question about an update, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Sure Gordon, I will post that has a separate question, Again thanks a ton for helping out.. cheers Sri